# PHP mktime() expects parameter

Tags: php, mktime

I'm not sure how to fix this one though, I've tried to search the same issue but I just got confused even more... any help please? Thanks in advance!

Error:

```
PHP Warning:  mktime() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in /home/web/public_html/sample.php on line 85
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
    $ArrDate=explode(' ',$datetime);
    $date=explode('/',$ArrDate[0]);
    $time=explode(':',$ArrDate[1]);
    // Check if new
    if(mktime($time[0],$time[1],$time[2],$date[1],$date[0],'20'.$date[2]) > $_COOKIE['newposts']) {
        $new='_new';
    }
?>
```

Line 85:

```
if(mktime($time[0],$time[1],$time[2],$date[1],$date[0],'20'.$date[2]) > $_COOKIE['newposts'])
```

Comment: Use `intval()`  to first convert them to int then they will get automatically promoted to long like `$time[0]=intval($time[0]);`

Comment: nice, thanks @Novice! :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Novice in the comments use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert the parameters to integers.

`intval($time[0])`